# Is it legal to put `FSharp.Core.dll` from FSharp redistributable package?

Tags: licensing, deployment

Is it legal to put `FSharp.Core.dll` from [FSharp Redist Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829875.aspx) into my application package and redistribute it with my application? I couldn't find any information about this.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "borrow". Do you mean are you allowed to redistribute it yourself with your application?

Comment: @Jon Hopkins, yes, I updated the question, thanks.

Comment: Did you just ask if it's all right to redistribute a part of the redistributable package? :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is legal. The page you linked to says the following:

> The F# redistributable package can be
>   added to a deployment project to
>   create a packaged, installable F#
>   application that installs the F#
>   runtime components when an application
>   is installed on a client computer.

You can also check the `redist.txt` file in `[program files]\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\` (or 9.0 if you're running 2008). You are allowed to redistribute libraries listed in that file and when you have F# installed, `FSharp.Core.dll` should be on that list.

Comment: I understood that part as I can put F# redist in my app package. Thanks.